# Applet for android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have developed one web application that runs under all browser via applet (core is written in c).

Now, I planned to develop the same application for android, but android does not support Java Applets, I want to invoke my application via browser so I have to call my application using like applet or ActiveX but both are not supported by Android, do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Applet with a core in C? Something is fishy here. Is it server-side C? Is it C somehow compiled to Java bytecode? Is it an ActiveX control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid you are on your own here. If you like to have at least some compatibility with different android devices and versions your options are

- native android app ( better in java, not in NDK  - full access to platform features, compatibility depends on your skill)
- crossplatform  javascript in browser ( limited access to android features and hardware,
  slow loading and compatibilitz depends on skill of cross platform toolkit provider )

supporting execution of arbitrary binary code in browser is security nightmare and is not going to happen on most browser under android

Answer (score 1):

Android browsers do not support applets. I believe no mobile browsers do. Unlike iOS or Windows Phone, Android does have a Java VM, but it is neither binary nor API compatible with Sun's.

For example, Android introduces a completely different layout model and a different set of UI widgets.

So, you have no choice but to write an Android app from scratch. Luckily, Android uses standard JNI, therefore you have a good chance to reuse your C code (you will need to compile it with Android NDK).

Android uses a sophisticated mechanism of cross application interaction, known as Intents. These allow an installed app to register to handle certain kinds of URLs. That's how a link in Android browser can invoke the YouTube app to play a video full screen. Your web page can use a similar mechanism to switch from browser to your dedicated app, and return to the original web page can also be handled naturally.

Note also that your app can use Web view to display HTML pages - either local content installed as part of the app, or dynamic content retrieved from arbitrary Web site. This view uses the full browser engine, including javascript, and can interact with your Java code, but not with the same API as javascript interacts with applets.

Answer (score 0):

Write native application based on your code or make your app more server side or webapp and drop applet